# How to config django for tastypie mongoengine in settings.py?

Tags: django, tastypie, mongoengine

I just starting build restful api. I start project cooking and create app to api. I use tastypie and tastypie-mongoengine addon.

In settings.py I config like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS +=('tastypie',
'tastypie_mongoengine',
'django.contrib.sessions')
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += ('django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',)
    import mongoengine
mongoengine.connect('cooking')
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
    )
SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
```

I comment this

```
#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
#        'NAME': '', # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
#        'USER': '', # Not used with sqlite3.
#        'PASSWORD': '', # Not used with sqlite3.
#        'HOST': '', # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
#        'PORT': '', # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
#    }
#}
```

But when I syncdb it says:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

I want Django project use Mongo too. How to config correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should not run `syncdb` if you are not using relational databases.

Read documentation of [MongoEngine](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django.html) on how to integrate it with Django.